# Google App script trigger does not work on simple custom function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am very new to google app script while having some experience both in javascript and python.

I am trying to run a very simple script [in this custom spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MSmpHKcMbZVjU0cd1-te78kEmZs_EeqcIQlXgj-bDIg/edit?usp=sharing), see row 1.

I am using the custom function feature, no apps/services deployed and I have full read/write authorizations.

I am developing some time conversion and duration calculation functions for a personal project, while trying to experiment with triggers starting with very simple functions.

The code associated with the trigger is indeed very simple: check the value of a predefined cell ("A1" in this case) and return its value in the cell where the function is invoked. As simple as possible, just to experiment with app script triggers:

```
function zain(){ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var a = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();  
 return a;}
```

To the effect of updating the cell value whenever any cell in the sheet is changed, I installed an onEdit() trigger on the function "zain()".

Now, the problem is: it does not work. The trigger log shows that onEdit() is successfully being completed, but the value in the cell where the function is invoked does not change, at all. It only seems to work whenever I re-paste the function or change the code and save it. Otherwise nothing.

I looked through all possible issues related to triggers in this forum and, contrarily to other cases, I could not find any working solution. I checked issues with trigger objects, spreadsheet access, but none of these solutions seems to be working/apply to my case.

If someone could be so kind to help in this matter, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Let me understand better tho: I am in fact changing the values on the spreadsheet, which means the trigger should be activated, and change the value in the cell, but it does not.

Comment: I am sorry but you might need to level up with me here... onEdit works when any cell on the spreadsheet is changed, regardless of function input. I see from the trigger log that it fires, the function is then invoked and should work properly. What would be the correct syntax then?

Comment: Okay let's reset if you're running this as a custom function then onEdit() triggers have nothing to do with it.  When it detects a change in it's input then it will return a value. But it has no inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Here is a onEdit(e) function that takes Celsius from A1 and calculates Fahrenheit in B1

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 1 && e.value ) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(e.value * (9 / 5) + 32);
  }
}

function zain(a) {
  return (a - 32) * 5 / 9;
}
```

in C1 put "=zain(B1)" then when B1 changes the value of A1 should end up in C1 but not because of the onEdit trigger it's because B1 has changed

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your patience. Upon implementing parts of your example code in my script, I believe I might have grossly misunderstood how onEdit() and triggers in general work. I expected onEdit() and function installed-triggers to automatically fire regardless of input, which is not the case. I believed onEdit() could solve the problem of custom functions that do not change result when implicit values (i.e. values that are indirectly calculated within the function, but not referenced in the sheet) are changed (like other cells that change the results of "if" conditions within the functions)

Comment: I will set yours as a solution, since it helped me understand the real workings of onEdit(). Thank you very much.

Comment: I think in the beginning of the question I misunderstood what you were asking.  I have a tendency not to read the entire question at times.

Comment: I know this is off topic but @Cooper how do you include the animated image?

Comment: I build it using Camtasia and export it as a gif and try to keep it as small as possible